# What's the role of mother-day in regard of a blessed life?

Tags: personal-practice, abhidhamma, sila, veneration

Being broad celebrated mothers-day today, my person thought to give this question space so that many might share reflections on it and pissible give others good inspirations:

**What role does a day like mothersday play for a blessed life, for a follower of the Buddhas Dhamma, and how would it be good spend by mind words and bodily deeds?**

*(Note that this is not asked for trade, exchange, stacks or what ever binds here, but for escape from this wheel)*

Answer (score 1):

I would like to paraphrase Luang Por Viradhammo, who cared for about 10 years for his elderly mother, in saying that it is good to have formal ways of bringing up and maintaining gratitude for ones mother lest we become complacent and let the importance they have in our being here fade from our minds.

With that in mind, I would say that exactly how you would internally use the formal occasion of mother's day is something only yourself can piece together. I hope the two links I am sharing can help give you a good starting point for reflection.

[Dhamma talk by Luang Por Sumedho about gratitude to parents](https://www.amaravati.org/audio/gratitude-to-parents/)

[Article by Ajahn Amaro](https://www.lionsroar.com/reflecting-on-a-mothers-love/)

Comment: Sadhu, Sadhu Here are some reads as well, for inspiration and maintain right view, gratitude: [Withou gratitude no success](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?topic=60.0)

Answer (score 1):

This is how u have a good day

Waking up as the third [last] watch of the night begins one gets up quickly thinking 'i will not indulge in the pleasures of sleeping, reclining and lazy stretching'.

Definitely not sleeping until sunrise snoring...

During the last watch of the night, sitting & pacing back & forth, one cleanses his mind of any qualities that would hold the mind in check.

During the day, sitting & pacing back & forth, cleanses his mind of any qualities that would hold the mind in check.

During the first watch of the night, sitting & pacing back & forth, he cleanses his mind of any qualities that would hold the mind in check.

During the second watch of the night, reclining on his right side, he takes up the lion's posture, one foot placed on top of the other, mindful, alert, with his mind set on getting up.

Practicing moderation in eating, guarding the senses and being devoted to wakefulness, that's how one cleanses the mind and has an auspicious day.

> You shouldn't chase after the past
>   or place expectations on the future.
>   What is past
>       is left behind.
>   The future
>       is as yet unreached.
>   Whatever quality is present
>   you clearly see right there,
>          right there.
>   Not taken in,
>   unshaken,
>   that's how you develop the heart.
>   Ardently doing
>   what should be done     today,
>   for — who knows? —  tomorrow
>       death.
>   There is no bargaining
>   with Mortality & his mighty horde.
>
> Whoever lives thus ardently,
>       relentlessly
>       both day & night,
>   has truly had an auspicious day:
>   so says the Peaceful Sage.
>   "'Monks, I will teach you the summary & exposition of one who has had an auspicious day.' Thus was it said, and in reference to this was it said."https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.131.than.html

Not only on mother's day should one do this.

If possible one can spend the mother's day absorbed in meditation, preferably nirodhasamapatti.

Comment: While living in a house and eating mothers off... Good to work on raw abounding first and get there most debt-free, since the bills come also if one maintains and trains household-equanimity.